# Spring service method thread safety

Tags: java, service, concurrency

I have a Spring 3 service method that I want to return a PrivateKey/PublicKey keyPair from - is it thread safe to have the KeyPairGenerator as an instance level variable in the service to avoid having to call KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(algo) and initializing it in the method call or should I keep the KeyPairGenerator local to the service method and call .getInstance(algo) and .initialize(...) for each method invocation, ie:

```
public KeyPair getKeyPair() throws ... {
    KeyPairGenerator keyGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(algo);
    keyGenerator.initialize(1024);
    return (keyGenerator.genKeyPair());
}
```

or

```
public KeyPair getKeyPair() throws ... {
    // use instance level keyGenerator that has been previously initialized
    return (keyGenerator.genKeyPair());
}
```

Are there possible concurrency issues with the second approach?  Is the performance penalty significant with the first approach?

Comment: btw, the parentheses in your return statement are unnecessary

Answer (score 4):

This question is not really Spring-related. I believe you are talking about [`KeyPairGenerator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyPairGenerator.html). The JavaDoc is not saying anything about thread safety, but there is a comment [in the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/security/KeyPairGenerator.java#520):

```
//  * although not specified, KeyPairGenerators could be thread safe,
//    so we make sure we do not interfere with that
```

Well, "*could be thread safe*" means absolutely nothing to me, especially after looking at [*access to keypairgenerator may not be thread safe*](https://bugs.launchpad.net/eucalyptus/+bug/431931) issue:

> the concurrency properties of the key pair generator are spi specific and may not be thread safe. this can cause failures which hang the front end.

So my advice would be to create new instance on every call, or [pool them](http://commons.apache.org/pool/).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and link.  I saw that comment in the source also - I guess it is up to the crypto provider to decide, and no guarantee is mandated by contract.  I think the question is also a Spring related question, as, if the KeyGenerator might *not* be threadsafe, I need to know if the default @Service annotated class behavoiur (Singleton I think?) is that there is a lock around method calls, or can they run concurrently and no shared state within a service is safe?

Comment: @jc1001: no, there is no synchronization and multiple threads can run the same bean method. You can pool  Spring bean just like EJB does, but it's a bit hacky.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz I'll do some tests on the KeyPairGenerator initialisation time and see if it warrants synchronizing a block around keyGenerator.genKeyPair() and if there's any benefit over having it local to the service method.